# c++20 ranges view to std::pmr::vector

Tags: c++, c++20, c++23

I'd like to use ranges-v3/std::ranges to populate a std::pmr::vector. However there seems to be no way to pass the memory resource into the following code...

```
 using namespace ranges;
 auto numbers = views::iota(0, 10) | to<std::pmr::vector<int>>();
```

`ranges::to` doesn't forward arguments onto the constructor of the container object, so going

```
 auto numbers = views::iota(0, 10) | to<std::pmr::vector<int>>(myMemoryResource);
```

causes the compiler to barf.

Is there a way to do this or is this an oversight in the ranges library?

Comment: In C++20, there is currently no direct way to specify a memory resource when using 'to' to convert a range into a std::pmr::vector.
If you want to use a std::pmr::vector with a specific memory resource, you can create the std::pmr::vector first and then use ranges::copy to populate it.

Comment: `std::ranges::to` does forward arguments. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4sbd1qcP3)

Comment: "*`ranges::to` doesn't forward arguments onto the constructor of the container object, so going*" This is *incorrect*, `ranges::to` does forward arguments and your example should be valid. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Note that range-v3's `to` does not accept additional arguments (it's just `r | to<C>()` or even `r | to<C>`), but C++23's `to` does.

Comment: I’m using ranges-v3 in C++20 as opposed to the standard lib in C++23, which would explain the difference. (Silly assumption on my behalf that they were equivalent).